# git cherry-pick vs git rebase

Tags: git

### Что есть

- Локальная гит ветка bugfix которая не обновлялась месяц, условно имеет + 5 коммитов по сравнению с удаленной веткой master
- Удаленная ветка master обновляется исключительно пул реквестами, и только обычным слиянием. каждый месяц в нее добавляется по 100 коммитов
- Программист который подливает в bugfix ветку изменения только с master и только pull --rebase

### Проблема

- При очередном git rebase origin/master возникло много конфликтов которые не касались изменения в ветке

### Решение

- Если вместо git **rebase** сделать **cherry-pick** то конфликтов не будет

  - git reset --hard origin/master
  - git cherry-pick HEAD...ORIG_HEAD (пяти комитов из origin/bugfix)

### Вопрос

- В чем разница между rebase и cherry-pick если разница коммитов одинаковая
- Откуда появились конфликты при rebase если в удаленную ветку (master) не происходят force push

### Размышления

- Я всегда думал что rebase делает что то подобное
- сравнивает 2 ветки Исходящая (master) и Входящая (bugfix) что бы найти разницу в коммитах
- переключает текущее состояние ветки bugfix на master состояние
- применяет разницу коммитов
- Я знаю про разные стратегии слияния (Recursive, Resolve, Octopus, Ours ...), но я думал они не применяются при rebase
- Банальные проблемы, типа локальные и удаленные ветки не обновленны или текущее состояние было грязным - исключено. Перед всеми работами запускались контрольные команды (git status, git fetch --all, git log --online, git branch -u origin/master)

Comment: [Why would git cherry-pick produce fewer conflicts than git rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251859)

Answer (score 2):

Есть подозрения что изменение в истории произошло в ветке bugfix  и вместо условных 5 комитов по факту сравнения идентификаторов комитов разница вышла в условные 10.

В любом случае вы всегда можете вернуться локально на старую локальную ветку bugfix используя git reflog и глазами сравнить идентификаторы комитов ожидаемой базы(от которой вы отсчитали условные 10 комитов) в обоих ветках

Comment: это исключено. Изменения в ветке bugfix это 5 коммитов по сравнению с мастером. Если бы их было бы условно 10, то cherry-pick также неправильно отработал. git reset --hard origin/master && git cherry-pick HEAD...ORIG_HEAD vs git rebase origin/master. Как эти две команды могут получить разный набор комитов?

Comment: под условными 10 я имел ввиду что они по сути своей точно такие же как и в orign, только по каким то обстоятельствам поменяли свои идентификаторы. если вы не потеряли историю того rabase и до сих пор можете воспроизвети эту ситуацию попробуйте запустить обе команды с флагами дебага GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY=5 git rebase origin/master. когда я попробовал сэмулировать вашу ситуацию(специально сделал похожие правки и применил как отдельный комит он все равно перевел базу без конфликтов). Чтобы воспроизвети нужно хорошенько запутать git:)